# How to convert null to not null. ERROR: Cannot insert the value NULL into column

Tags: sql-server, ssms

```
ALTER TABLE Sale 
    ALTER COLUMN CustomerID nvarchar(10) NOT NULL
```

I get this error:

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 17
> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CustomerID', table 'LAPTOP.dbo.Sale'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.

Comment: Insert a any non-null string in the column `CustomerID`.

Answer (score 1):

When you alter a column and change its nullability from `NULL` to `NOT NULL` SQL Server must first check the existing rows to ensure no row violates the new NULL criteria.

Before running the alter statement you must remove any existing null values:

```
update dbo.Sale 
set CustomerId = 'some default value' 
where CustomerId is null;
```